# Form Send Different Value From Database

Tags: php, forms, post, input

This question seems like a duplicate question, but I searched here and I could not find a question very similar to this.

I have a simple text field.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Product Name" name="pro_id" id="pro_id">
```

User can type product name(There is a small ajax script which can suggest products when user typing).

As $_POST['pro_id'], I need to send Product ID(Need to get from Database) instead of user typed product name.

Is it possible? If it is possible how to do it?

Comment: where is your ajax script code?

Comment: Ajax script only do when user type a name, it auto suggests names getting from database....

Comment: show the full code along with `ajax` and `php` data

Comment: So in pro_id field you will type the name of product then through ajax in a php page its searches for a product and then get the id ??

Comment: @Plum No, In ajax I have a query like `select * from product where pro_name like '%".$usertype."%' order by pro_name`. It is like google search. User can select product name, After that when user click the submit button I need to send the product id  instead of product name.

Comment: @Sasa1234   You can do this with a jquery suggest https://github.com/w3shaman/jquery-coolautosuggest. in this plugin after selecting a product the id is captured in a hidden variable and then you can trigger a evernt to again send the id to another function